# ACTIVESCAFFOLD: column sorting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have 2 models say 'foo' and 'bar', such as foo has_many :bars, and bar belongs to foo. And they both have a 'name' field.

```
active_scaffold :bar do |config|        
    config.columns = [:name, :foo_id]
    config.columns[:foo_id].label = 'Foo Name'
end
```

in the controller and in the helper

```
def foo_id_column(b)
    return link_to b.foo.name, foo_url(b.foo)
end
```

And this works just fine but whenever I click on the table header "Foo Name" instead of getting sort by the name displayed it is getting sorted by the foo_id, meaning, say we have 2 foo objects "a" with id 2 and "b" with id 1, then on clicking the "FooName" column it is displaying as "b" row first then 'a' instead of 'a' then 'b'. How to change the code so that the activescaffold uses the name content instead of the id for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the belongs_to/has_many associations are defined in your models, then ActiveScaffold will do all of this for you (including sorting by foo.name) - no custom helper method needed:

```
active_scaffold :bar do |config|        
    config.columns = [:name, :foo]
end
```

This way is also kinder to your DB, since ActiveScaffold will :include the association into the finder for listing bars, avoiding the N-query issue that would be seen in your sample code (fetching each foo record separately when rendering the list of bars)